# Openbravo ant build fails

Tags: ant, openbravo

I am trying to setup openbravo on eclipse environment with the above URL.
Development stack setup is done successfully. (ANT, Java, Postgresql)

At the openbravo source directory when i  apply the command

> ant install.source

Build failure due to errors -

```
/home/pos/sourcecode_openbravo/Openbravo-3.0MP21/build.xml:480: The following error occurred while executing this line:
480     <ant dir="${base.src}" target="compile.complete.development" inheritAll="true" inheritRefs="true" />


/home/pos/sourcecode_openbravo/Openbravo-3.0MP21/src/build.xml:874: The following error occurred while executing this line:
874       <jvmarg line="${env.CATALINA_OPTS}" />

/home/pos/sourcecode_openbravo/Openbravo-3.0MP21/src/build.xml:880: Directory 
880       <jvmarg value="-Djava.io.tmpdir=${env.CATALINA_BASE}/temp" />

/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/openbravo/WEB-INF/lib creation was not successful for an unknown reason
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a permission problem.
See the related section 'Permission issues' in [openbravo wiki](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Installation/Troubleshooting#Permission_issues)

**EDIT**
for the remaining issues, i believe the properties `base.src`, `CATALINA_OPTS` and `CATALINA_BASE` are not set properly. Check this via :

```
<echo>
 $${base.src} => ${base.src}
 $${env.CATALINA_OPTS} => ${env.CATALINA_OPTS}
 $${env.CATALINA_BASE} => ${env.CATALINA_BASE}
</echo>
```

or simply output all available properties use :

```
<echoproperties/>
```

also consider, before using ${env.whatever} you need to use :

```
<property environment="env"/>
```

before !

Comment: Thanks! it resolved one of the listed Issue. Any suggestions on the remaining issues.

Answer (score 0):

*/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/openbravo/WEB-INF/lib creation was not successful for an unknown reason*

**Give the permission to webapps folder**

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/
```

Answer (score 0):

> /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/openbravo/WEB-INF/lib creation was not
>   successful for an unknown reason

it seem permission problem. It is important to always us the correct user account to start / stop tomcat!

Conceptually there are two user accounts involved in working with Openbravo:

command-line user used to work with files & compile Openbravo
user account used by Apache Tomcat service
There are several overlapping areas in which one of the accounts needs to access and modify files from the other account in both directions.

To avoid any problems Openbravo strongly recommends to run Apache Tomcat services with the same user account which is used on command line. As that way the above topic will be perfectly solved easily.

source: http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Installation/Custom/Apache_Tomcat